# How to perform a file upload to REST service?

Tags: spring, rest, kotlin, testing, jax-rs

I have the following method in the Spring REST controller

```
@PostMapping("/uploadFile", consumes=["multipart/form-data"])
fun uploadFile(@RequestParam("fileType") fileType: FileType?,
               @RequestParam("fileContentType") fileContentType: FileContentType?,
               @RequestParam("projectId", required=false) projectId: UUID?,
               @RequestParam("fileId", required = false) fileId:UUID?,
               @RequestParam("description", required=false) description: String?,
               @RequestParam("file") file: MultipartFile): UUID {
```

My objective is to test this service. I need to upload a file and in the same  time give to service wrong "fileId", then parse ErrorMessage. Please tell me how to perform such request? What should I use JAX-RS? ResteasyClient? I have tried ResteasyClient

```
  val inputStream: InputStream = Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("application.properties")
    val upload = MultipartFormDataOutput()
    upload.addFormData("file", inputStream, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE, "mytarfile.tar")
    var request = ClientRequest("http://localhost:$port/api/v1.0/files/uploadFile")
    request.formParameter("fileId","test")
    request.header("Authorization", "Bearer $accessToken")
    request.body(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE, upload)
    val response = request.post(String::class.java)
```

but it doesn't work

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003100: You cannot send both form parameters and an entity body
```

Moreover ClientRequest is depricated and it is recommended to move to JAX-RS 2.0, could you tell me how to do that??

Comment: instead of `formParameter` try setting `queryParam`

Comment: @sidgate It does work, thank you. But ClientRequest is still deprecated. I should to get rid of it.

Comment: Finally I have solved this issue using RestTemplate https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-multipart-upload